# Прошу помочь с циклами в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! У меня есть код, который в моем понимании должен забирать файлы из директории, а далее есть функции, которые обрабатывают все файлы поочередно. Ниже начало кода и пример одной из функций

```
for name in glob.glob('converted_dir/*.xlsx'):
wb = load_workbook(name)
sheet = wb['TDSheet']

# Model_name
def model_name_fun():
    result = []
    for i in range(19, 70):
        model_name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        if model_name is not None:
            result.append(model_name)
    return result
```

Но, обрабатывается лишь последний добавленный файл из директории. Понимаю, что нужно прописать цикл, но не пойму что и как. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас модел фан не вызывается

Comment: вызывается далее в коде. Тут функция для примера, т.к. возможно, цикл нужен именно для всех следующих

Answer (score 0):

```
# Model_name
def model_name_fun(sheet):
    result = []
    for i in range(19, 70):
        model_name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        if model_name is not None:
            result.append(model_name)
    return result

model_names = []

for name in glob.glob('converted_dir/*.xlsx'):
    wb = load_workbook(name)
    sheet = wb['TDSheet']
    model_names.append(model_name_fun(sheet))
```

Если в `model_names` нужен плоский список, то вместо `append` в конце вызываете `extend`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sheets=dict() 
for name in glob.glob('converted_dir/*.xlsx'):
    wb = load_workbook(name)
    sheets[name] = wb['TDSheet']
```

Потом в вызове, который я не вижу

```
def model_name_fun(sheet):
   .... 

for sheet in sheets.values():
    result = model_name_fun(sheet)
```